# registering ECS tasks with codeship

Tags: amazon-ecs, codeship

I am trying to deploy an application to AWS ECS using codeship. I have my docker-compose file and everything is ready to be deployed. Codeship documentation says to do something like this in the `codeship-steps.yml` file:

```
aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json file:///deploy/tasks/backend.json
aws ecs update-service --service my-backend-service --task-definition backend
```

My question is, is this file `file:///deploy/tasks/backend.json` something I have to provide manually or is it created automatically as well as the ECS task. because I keep getting this error from codeship

> An error occurred (ClientException) when calling the RunTask operation: TaskDefinition not found.

Comment: Also interested to know how.

Answer (score 0):

`file:///deploy/tasks/backend.json` is something you provide to `aws ecs register-task-definition`.

Looked it up [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/create-task-definition.html), this will generate the structure of that file you want:

`aws ecs register-task-definition --generate-cli-skeleton`

You can then modify it, after throwing it in `backend.json`, for instance (provided you redirect the output of the command into a file called `backend.json`).

If you look at the suggested service definition:

```
awsdeployment:
  image: codeship/aws-deployment
  encrypted_env_file: aws-deployment.env.encrypted
  environment:
    - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
  volumes:
    - ./:/deploy
```

You can see that `./` is mapped to the `/deploy` mount point. This means that if in your repo, you create a directory called tasks, then you place your json file there, and you should be all set.